# Laço "for" dentro de outro "for" (repetição aninhada)

Tags: c#, algoritmo, loop, for

Gostaria de poupar essas 9 linhas repetidas em meu código:

```
for (int n1 = 1, n2 = 1; n2 < 11;){
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//1
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//2
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//3
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//4
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//5
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//6
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//7
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//8
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//9
    Console.WriteLine(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2)); n2++;//10
    n1 = n1 - 9;
}
```

É um laço `for` simples que gera a Tabuada da Multiplicação completa, o código é repetido 10x, cada `Console.Write` escreve um trecho de coluna em uma mesma linha por repetição. Pensei em aninhar um `for` dentro de outro, como por exemplo:

```
for (int n1 = 1, n2 = 1; n2 < 11;){
    Console.Write(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2) + "\t"); n1++;//9x
    for (n1==10){
        Console.WriteLine(n1 + "x" + n2 + "=" + (n1 * n2)); n2++;//1x
        n1 = n1 - 9;
    }
}
```

Nessa sintaxe, surgem inúmeros erros de *Expected*...

Encontrei esse artigo [C# - Nested Loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_nested_loops.htm), mas nenhum resolveu. Alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Última versão, consegui deixar o output das colunas lado a lado:

```
using System;
namespace ConsoleApp1{
    class Program{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Console.WriteLine("\nTABUADA MULTIPLICAÇÃO\n");
            for (int n1 = 1, n2 = 1; n2 < 11;){
                Console.Write($"{n1}x{n2}={n1*n2}\t"); n1++;//9x
                if (n1 == 10){
                    Console.WriteLine($"{n1}x{n2}={n1*n2}"); n2++;//1x
                    n1 = n1 - 9;
                }
            }
Console.WriteLine("\nDigite qualquer tecla para sair.");
Console.ReadKey();
}}}
```

[Veja no **GitHub**.](https://github.com/LucasBonafe/CSExercises/blob/master/Tabuada.cs)

Answer (score 2):

Este código não faz o menor sentido, tem erros básicos de sintaxe. Seria assim:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        for (int n1 = 1; n1 < 11; n1++) {
            for (int n2 = 1; n2 < 11; n2++) WriteLine($"{n1:d2} x {n2:d2} = {n1 * n2:d2}");
            WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/7bHWsO). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rlrxq2). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/NestedFor.cs).

Comment: Muito obrigado, seu código está bem melhor otimizado, vou pesquisar um pouco mais sobre o `$` e `{}` dentro do `WriteLine`. Consegui rodar substituindo o segundo `for` por um `if`.
Algum meio de fazer o output printar as colunas lado a lado?

Comment: Aqui mesmo tem tudo sobre isto. É possível fazer com um `if`, mas não gosto, é contra intuitivo. Dá pra fazer em colunas, mas dá um pouco mais de trabalho e precisaria inverter a execução, sem falar na falta de espaço, aí precisaria quebrar em blocos que é um complicador a mais.